# how to configure same Spring JPARepository With multiple datasouces?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

i have multiple Spring JPA repositories in a package com.example.repositories. I have multiple databases, each one associated with a client. Table structure of all databases is same but only have client specific data.

I want to associate my repositories with all the data sources. Although i know how to configure multiple data sources with repositories in different packages as mentioned in below article.But in my case i want to use same repositories with different datasources.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Is there any way that i can configure same Spring JPARepository With multiple datasources?

Comment: Take a look to the following links: https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing and https://www.websparrow.org/spring/spring-boot-dynamic-datasource-routing-using-abstractroutingdatasource

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem.